# how can i read multiple variable into Plotly.newPlot data at a time

Tags: javascript, php, plot, charts, plotly

I am new to this Plotly.newPlot ,here my data like this in test.php:

```
<?php 
 $testx1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
 $testy1 = "11,22,33,44,55,66,77";
 $testx2 = "5,6,7,8,9,10";
 $testy2 = "10,20,30,40,50,60,70";  
?>
```

You can see my Plotly.newPlot in `view.php`:

```
var trace1 = {
   x: [ <?php echo $testx1 ;?> ],
   y: [ <?php echo $testy2 ;?> ],
  fill: 'none',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'Mean'
};
var trace2 = {
   x: [ <?php echo $testx2 ;?> ],
   y: [ <?php echo $testy2 ;?> ],
  fill: 'none',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: '5 percentile'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
    title:'',
    xaxis: {
    title: 'GA (weeks)',
    titlefont: {
    family: '"Roboto", sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size: 14,color: '#7f7f7f'
           }
    },
    yaxis: {
    title: 'BPD mm',
    titlefont: {
    family: '"Roboto", sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
        size: 14,color: '#7f7f7f'
        }
    }
   };
var config = {
     modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud'],
      displaylogo: false
    };
var config1 = {
         displayModeBar: false
    };
$(document).ready(function(){
    Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv', data, layout, config1);
    Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv1', data, layout, config1);
    Plotly.newPlot('chartdiv2', data, layout, config1);
    });
```

In above code I am reading `$testx1,$testy1` and `$testx2,$testy2` this variable from another `test.php` file,so here my query is here my problem is

If I add one more variable in `test.php` how can i read that variable in charts
dynamically with out hard coding.

If I delete variables in `test.php` i am getting error bez what ever I deleted that variable declared in `view.php`.

So how can I read those variables with out hard coding like `<?php echo $testx1 ?>,<?php echo $testy1 ?>` into `view.php`. 
If it is possible it really appreciate .
Thanks

Comment: why not pass array from php

Comment: HI @joyBlanks ,thanks for your response ,could you please explain ,i did not get.Thanks